# XNA graphicsdevice.present crashes on "value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: graphics, error-handling, xna

I have an XNA application, that when run on a certain laptop (dell, Win 7 64bit) will crash.
Sometimes it crashes after a few minutes, sometimes it takes many hours, but it always crashes   eventually.
The application is written in XNA4.0 VS2010
I had to add an event to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException just to catch this exception,
here is the stack trace :

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Present(tagRECT* pSource, tagRECT* pDest, HWND__* hOverride)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.IGraphicsDeviceManager.EndDraw()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.EndDraw()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DrawFrame()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.RunOneFrame()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.ApplicationIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
   at Moof.Moof.Run()
   at Moof.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: I think what's happening is that your video device invalidated. If that's the case, it'll show up with DirectX in debug mode - you can find info on how to do that here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/01/31/debugging-xna-graphics-problems.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your graphics drivers, links below.

Intel: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/

AMD/ATI: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

NVIDIA: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, it's an nVidia card and drivers are the latest.